# I am searching for a software that monitors activity on my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, monitoring

I already found this [app](https://camwebapp.com/) which is not really doing what I want, because it is for games and I don't want to see my cpu usage.

I am specifically searching for [this](https://youtu.be/hEd4UW5f7s4?t=13m50s) app.

I tried to find but I didn't. So if somebody knows it it would be pretty great if not here is what I am searching for:

*A software which*
**tracks which programs I use for how long**, **has a categorizing feature** and **shows me my usage**.

So basically a one which does what was in the video I linked up on *"this app"*.

*Trying to find a software just gave me "spyware" and "company monitoring" apps like for a network which not match my criteria.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program in the video that you linked to is called [Rescue Time](https://www.rescuetime.com)

Features you requested:

1. tracks which programs I use for how long

   ```
   A.Tracks time spent on applications and websites, giving you an accurate picture of your day.
   ```
2. Has a categorizing feature and shows me my usage

   ```
   A.Gives you detailed reports and data based on your activity.
   ```

I have never used this program.

Comment: oh dude you saved my life!! :D Thanks man. Will accept your anwser when I am able to ^^

Comment: Please edit your answer after you read and incorporate the [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality). You should have some experience using the software. What exactly did you like about it, and what did you not like as much? How does the software match each requirement in the question? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Eventlog in windows hold every activity detail..

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP was asking for a specific application.

Comment: That is also an application...

Comment: Most people don't give importance to that but that is also a powerful application

Comment: Is it? Your answer doesn't show that :) If you think this really answers the question, maybe you [edit] your answer and show how it does so? How can *Eventlog* be used to track "which programs I use for how long, has a categorizing feature and shows me my usage"? Answers here must show exactly the proposed solution fits the question. One-liners usually don't ;) // PS: None of the down-votes is mine – but they show I'm not the only one thinking your answer needs some improvements at least. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be a valid answer if you detailed how it fits the requirements.

Comment: Open task manager app history tab in windows 10

Comment: Settings network usage ...